# How to apply makeup on face with different principled bsdf shader?

Tags: shaders, texture-painting, photorealism

I have made a human model with a color map, and I want to paint my makeup with different IOR and other values on different map so it won't mess with the skin detail. Is there any way to make a mask so that I can paint a makeup color map that also become a mask of a shader?

Comment: Sure, create a mask, add a second shader and use a mix shader node to add your makeup on top.

Comment: Drive a Mix Shader node’s Factor with the resulting Black And White texture.